# Quebrado layout perto de "tags ignoradas"

Tags: bug, status-pronto, layout

O layout encontra-se quebrado junto das opções para controlar as tags que o sistema deve ignorar para o meu utilizador:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Este problema pode ser visto na página das preferências do utilizador que é acedido a partir do endereço:

```
https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/xxx

xxx = código do utilizador.
```

Ou simplesmente https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

Comment: Bug de tradução relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2167/problema-de-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-nas-prefer%C3%AAncias-de-ignorar-tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem que passar a seguinte `position` de `absolute` para `relative`

```
#add-ignored table {
    position: relative;
}
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>