# Problema de tradução nas preferências de ignorar tags

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, localização

https://stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[O bug no leiaute já foi reportado](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/860/215). O problema está na tradução da segunda opção:

- `<label for="hideIgnoredTrue">&nbsp;Ocultar perguntas em suas tags ignoradas</label>`
- `<label for="hideIgnoredFalse">&nbsp;Desativar perguntas em suas tags ignoradas</label>`

O que seria "desativar" uma pergunta? Acho que a opção de "ocultar" está correta, mas *"gray out"* deveria ser traduzida de alguma outra forma (sugestões?).

Answer (score 4):

Uma tradução bastante usada no Brasil para *gray out* é **esmaecer**.

Além de acertar isso, eu também mudaria o "*em* suas tags ignoradas" para "*com* suas tags ignoradas" no final das mensagens.

Comment: "Convertido em uma resposta por [bfavaretto♦](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/users/74/bfavaretto)". Geralmente eu vejo as suas conversões no sentido oposto :P

Comment: Foi pressão comunitária :)