# Como fazer com que as tags que desejo ignorar não sejam exibidas ao invés de serem exibidas com baixa opacidade?

Tags: bug, suporte, status-pronto, tags

Diferentemente da versão global do SO, aqui no SO pt as tags que você ignora tem apenas a opacidade reduzida ao invés de totalmente ocultas. Porque isso? É possível oculta-las totalmente, assim como no SO global?

EDIT: Após a resposta do @bfavaretto eu me dei conta que existe a opção de suprimir as tags ignoradas, mas aparentemente existe um bug de UI no perfil onde eu não consigo clicar nesta opção já que as tags estão em sobreposição;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: The layout issue will be fixed in build rev 2014.12.6.2082

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No SO original funciona igual. As tags "ignoradas" não são totalmente omitidas. Talvez você não tenha percebido isso lá porque o volume de perguntas é muito maior, e a coisa fica mais dissolvida.

De qualquer maneira, em ambos os sites existe uma opção para omitir completamente essas tags. Fica no seu perfil, em *preferências* > *tags ignoradas* > *Ocultar perguntas em suas tags ignoradas*.

Link para as preferências do seu usuário: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/preferences/me

---

Detalhe: essa opção está escondida atrás de um botão, devido a um [bug](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/860/quebrado-layout-perto-de-tags-ignoradas) do sistema.

Answer (score 2):

Uma outra opção ainda é ver as perguntas sem respostas apenas das suas tags

https://pt.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged?tab=mytags

Comment: Essa também é boa hein! Não conhecia ela, pode ser bem útil em algumas situações.

Comment: @Math descobri esses dias, e achei muito massa poder pesquisar inclusive nas mais antigas, pena estar sem muito tempo pra responder

Answer (score 1):

Você pode acompanhar apenas as perguntas da tag do seu interesse.

Exemplo: [Perguntas recentes de JavaScript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript?sort=newest&pageSize=15).

É uma possibilidade. Pode não ser a melhor solução, mas é adotada em muitos casos.

Funciona muito bem se você quiser acompanhar apenas uma ou duas tags. Caso queira acompanhar diversas tags é melhor ir pela resposta do @bfavaretto mesmo.